Merge multidocument into 1 Document
I want to make codes to combine multidoc into 1 Doc but I'm newbe in VBA, so the code as below I copied and adjusted something but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me to fix this code.
Thank you in advanced
Sub Main()

Dim Wapp As Word.Application
Dim MainDoc As Word.Document
Dim TargDoc As Word.Document
Dim cntr As Integer
Dim Select_Files As Variant
Dim numofRow As Long

Set Wapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set MainDoc = New Document
Set TargDoc = New Document
Wapp.Visible = True


'Lets validate file path first
For cntr = 4 To Sheet15.Cells(Sheet15.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If VBA.Dir(Sheet15.Range("A" & cntr).Value) = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "File " & Sheet15.Range("A" & cntr).Value & " doesn't exists.."
            Exit Sub
            
    
    End If
Next cntr

Select_Files = Sheet15.Range("A4:A" & Sheet15.Cells(Sheet15.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value

MainDoc.Open (Select_Files(LBound(Select_Files), 1))

For cntr = LBound(Select_Files) + 1 To UBound(Select_Files)
    
    TargDoc.Open (Select_Files(cntr, 1))
    
        If MainDoc.InsertPages(MainDoc.GetNumPages() - 1, TargDoc, 0, TargDoc.GetNumPages(), True) = True Then
            
        End If
        
       
    TargDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    

Next cntr

    MainDoc.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MergeWord").Range("A1").Value & Application.PathSeparator & "Markedup DWG Devider.docx"
    MainDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    MsgBox "Completed"
        
End Sub


Please clarify the meaning of it doesn't work. Is there any error?
